# Is TUI Premium Economy’s baggage offloaded first?

Tags: luggage, airports, airlines, tui

Is TUI Dreamliner Premium Economy’s baggage unloaded first at the arrival airport?

Comment: Mine is usually last even though I have large "priority luggage" signs on my bags...

Comment: Just because it is offloaded first won't mean it will turn up on the belt first. What is really your question? To have your bag among the first on the belt or as little weather exposure as possible, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

There’s no way to guess and you can’t give an answer for every situation. It’s a hit and miss.

In theory, you should be given a *priority luggage* tag and your bags should be offloaded first.

Depends on the baggage handlers and how they load the plane and unload it. Sometimes when the flight is delayed or in a rush they will just want to load the bags on in any order.

Additionally, if a passenger is late and their baggage has to be removed the order could be messed up.

Comment: What "theory" are you referring to?